# Linking local file to remote file path for FTP

Tags: ftp, sftp, filezilla

I'm currently using FileZilla for FTP from my local machine to my server. Every time I want to transfer a file I have to select the file path that I want by navigating through the directory tree in FileZilla. Is there a way I can specify that the local file should always go to the same file path on the server?

I've set the default directory that FileZilla should go to when establishing a connection so I'm relatively close to where I want to be, but it would be nice to just click upload and have the file go to exactly where it should every time.

Is there a way to do this or another tool that can accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Bookmarks** to do it:

See this link in the filezilla doc [here](https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/getting-started/bookmark-a-directory/)

Extracting information from the doc:

**To Create a Bookmark**

1. Open a connection and navigate to the local and remote directories that you want to save in a bookmark.
2. In the main menu, click on Bookmarks > Add bookmark…. Alternatively, press CTRL-B.
3. Select either Global bookmark or Site-specific bookmark from the Type option group.
4. Enter a name for the bookmark. This will be displayed in the Bookmark menu.

[...]

9. Click on OK.

**To Use a bookmark**

1. Open a connection to the remote server.
2. In the main menu, click on Bookmarks and the name of the bookmark you want to use.

I hope it helps you

Comment: Ok I will add it

Comment: Appreciate the update. Good stuff. =)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this or another tool that can accomplish what I'm looking for?

### FileZilla

I used to use FileZilla but got fed up with it continually nagging me to update it and I didn't find the bookmarks system very handy.

There are lots of other tools that might do what you want.

### Windows Explorer

A tool you already have is Windows Explorer - which can open an FTP URL and be used as a drag-n-drop target. It may work for some use-cases - e.g. copying a whole folder hierarchy to an FTP server with a single mouse gesture.

### ncFtp

Another example the venerable [ncftp](https://www.ncftp.com/) has a [ncftpput](https://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html) command that has a large set of options. I'd run it from a batch file.

---

Footnote

### DIY

I have to admit that I wrote myself an FTP copy tool in Go (golang) for copying changed files to an FTP or SFTP server or mapped file-server. I use this for publishing revised web-pages etc. It duplicates the folder hierarchy onto the server where needed. Now I just type `ftpsync` from an open command prompt and any recently changed files in folders listed in a local config (including subdirectories) get copied to the server. It can exclude subfolders with special names (e.g. "old", "test") and has a whitelist of filename extensions so source-only files don't get transferred. etc etc. I keep thinking I should throw it onto GitHub but there are dozens of existing tools for this sort of thing.